# How to add a javascript value into my SQL table?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm kind of new to javascript but I'm currently working on my website:

When I press a button, javascript generates a random number (for example: Your Coins: 25) and then I need to connect to my 'members' table and add 25 to the 'coins' field. (I'm already connected with mysql in the php code if this matters.)

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question is unfortunately off-topic. You need to include [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it is easier for others to understand your problem.

Comment: If you are doing some kind of "currency" or in-game reward type system, 100% absolutely do _not_ generate the number of coins a player receives in javascript. Any browser could modify the JS to generate a billion coins each time instead of a random number.

Comment: PHP runs before the page loads, javascript after. When you generate the number, you need to submit it to a PHP page to process the database insert. Look into ajax calls.

Comment: Are you using JavaScript on the backing in NodeJS or client side in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the browser sends a request to the server, which, on its turn parses it. This is the time when your HTML is generated and your PHP runs. When the HTML is generated and ready, it is being sent to the web-browser. The HTML might contain `script` tags which are pointing to js files via the `src` attribute, or `script` tags which contain Javascript code, but before the server sends the response, the Javascript files are not loaded, Javascript code inside the scripts will not be executed. When the response arrives to the web-browser, it parses the HTML, loads the external js, css files and pictures and executes the Javascript code.

So, when your Javascript generates the value, it is running on the user's web-browser, remote from the server. Therefore, from this point the Javascript code should send an [AJAX request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) to the server. This will post a request to the server, which, on its turn will receive and parse it. You can post parameters when you send an AJAX request. jQuery has an [easy-to-use variation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Your server will receive the request with your parameters and you will be able to read the parameters via `$_GET` or `$_POST`, which are associative `array`s containing parameters with their names used as indexes. You can use those to write your query.

All this is well-documented, if you watch a few tutorials, you should be able to solve the problem. On the other hand the commenters and the other answerer are right when they tell you that you should never trust the browser to generate sensitive data, as hackers could easily see what requests are being sent from the web-browser and would send similar posts where they would be "lucky".

Answer (score 2):

If it's "coins" then you probably won't want it to generate client side,  otherwise someone would be able to call your java script function with any number they like and add in millions of coins!

The other way is to have PHP generate the number for you.

You can use something like jQuery's $.get function to call your php script with the action of "adding a random number of coins"  and the php script can return the random number to java script via JSON for it to be displayed.